# matlab image position and size

Tags: image, matlab

We are using MATLAB to display an image with specific position and size using this code:

```
type1 = imread('20.jpg', 'jpg');
image(type1,[10,10,10,10])
```

Produces Mtalab error:

> Error using image
>   Incorrect number of arguments specified

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is this:

```
type1 = imread('20.jpg','jpg')
figure('Position', [10,10,10,10])
image(type1)
```

I don't think `image()` can take a position argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to adjust the position of the image within the `axes` you will need to [specify the `XData` and `YData`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image-properties.html?refresh=true#zmw57dd0e379005) which are the X and Y extents of the image.

```
image(type1, 'XData', [10 20], 'YData', [10 20])
```

The other options are to create a figure the size you want and then set the parent axes to take up the entire figure.

```
hfig = figure('Position', [10 10 10 10]);
hax = axes('Parent', hfig, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);
image(type1, 'Parent', hax);
```